# Objects array serialized by Swagger in multipart/form-data request not recognized by ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, multipartform-data

I have an array of objects (named `propertyOptions`) being sent via multipart/form-data request. Everything works fine when being sent using `axios` from FE application, but it fails when sent using Swagger UI.

Here is how `axios` serializes the payload:

[image]

And here is what Swagger does

[image]

Controller

[image]

Endpoint

[image]

Request model

[image]

Are there any serialization options to be configured for Swagger to fix this or any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your controller and payload/class definitions with the relevant annotations?

Comment: @Helen, posted it